# Migrate from Multiprocess to MPI in python

Tags: python, mpi, hpc, multiprocess, mpi4py

I'm tring to move a code from multiprocces to MPI using python becouse I'm moving my code in an HPC. In this why I wnat to span the procces on several nodes and aovid to use all the ram of a signle node.

Can you help me implementing it? I have tried so far this.

Multiprocces.map code:

```
import Home
import pickle
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
import time
import os

def run(a):
    name=a['name']
    people=a['people']
    save_path='res_semi_def'
    save_path='res_semi_def'
    path=os.getcwd()
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),save_path)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),save_path))
    if sum(people.values())>0:
        start=time.time()
        home=Home.Home(people)
        try:
            home.simulate()
            print name,time.time()-start, '[s]'
            fname=str(name)+'.pkl'
            with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),save_path,fname), "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(home.Consumption,f)
            #fname=str(name)+'_person.pkl'
            #with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),save_path,fname), "wb") as f:
            #    pickle.dump(home.personsList,f)
        except Exception as e:
            print name, 'error', e
            pass



def main():
    p = Pool(6)     
    fname='censimento2011_full_par.pkl'
    with open(fname,'r') as f:
        houses=pickle.load(f)
    house=[{'name':name, 'people':people} for name, people in zip(houses.iterkeys(),houses.itervalues())]
    #name,people=zip(*houses.iteritems())
    #p.map(partial(run,int(name)), people)
    start_t=time.time()
    a=p.map(run, house)
    p.close()
    print time.time()-start_t, 'Total time[s]'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here the main with mpiy4py:

```
def main():
    comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD
    if comm.rank==0:
        fname='censimento2011_full_par.pkl'
        with open(fname,'r') as f:
            houses=pickle.load(f)
        house=[{'name':name, 'people':people} for name, people in zip(houses.iterkeys(),houses.itervalues())]
    else:
        house=None

    my_work=comm.scatter(house)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But with this code I get this error:

```
===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 54118 RUNNING AT compute-0-8
=   EXIT CODE: 4
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
[proxy:0:0@compute-0-5] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:909): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:0@compute-0-5] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:2@compute-0-7] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:909): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:2@compute-0-7] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:2@compute-0-7] main (pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:206): demux engine error waiting for event
[proxy:0:1@compute-0-6] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:909): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:1@compute-0-6] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:1@compute-0-6] main (pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:206): demux engine error waiting for event
[proxy:0:0@compute-0-5] main (pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:206): demux engine error waiting for event
srun: error: compute-0-5: task 0: Exited with exit code 7
srun: error: compute-0-7: task 2: Exited with exit code 7
srun: error: compute-0-6: task 1: Exited with exit code 7
[mpiexec@compute-0-5] HYDT_bscu_wait_for_completion (tools/bootstrap/utils/bscu_wait.c:76): one of the processes terminated badly; aborting
[mpiexec@compute-0-5] HYDT_bsci_wait_for_completion (tools/bootstrap/src/bsci_wait.c:23): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@compute-0-5] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:218): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@compute-0-5] main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:344): process manager error waiting for completion
```

Which is the correct why to implement the procces with mpi4py?

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues with your code.

1. You need to specify the root in the scatter operation.
   `house = comm.scatter(house, root=0)`
2. The recommended way to access the rank is
   `rank = comm.Get_rank()`

Here is an example from https://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    data = [(i+1)**2 for i in range(size)]
else:
    data = None
data = comm.scatter(data, root=0)
assert data == (rank+1)**2
```